# Use other CSV separator with p:dataExporter and p:dataTable

Tags: csv, jsf, primefaces, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export my datatable as CSV file with semicolon ';' as separator. This is not possible with Primefaces Dataexporter cause the separator is always comma ',' and pre/post processing is not possible only with PDF/EXCEL: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml

So my question is: Do i have to write my own method for it ? how can I get my Data from my Datatable and save it as CSV? Can someone give me a simple example cause I dont know where to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in the upcoming PrimeFaces 6.3 Release.

See this ticket: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/48

Fixed with PR: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/3822

You can build a 6.3-SNAPSHOT from the GitHub Source or patch your 6.2 version with that PR if you wish.

Comment: I don’t think primetek has announced an official release date but they usually do major releases every 6 months